# Always returning × instead of x in php string, how to prevent this?

Tags: php, string

I'm having real problems trying to return a string in php with a character `x` rather than a symbol `×`.

I'm trying work it back right from source and I have even tried these php `str_replaces` functions...

```php
<?php 

$title = get_the_title();

var_dump($title);
// string(20) "Standard UK 4×4"

var_dump(str_replace('×', 'x', $title));
// string(20) "Standard UK 4×4"

var_dump(str_replace('&#215;','x', $title));
// string(15) "Standard UK 4×4"

var_dump(str_replace('4×4', '4x4', $title));
// string(20) "Standard UK 4×4"
```

None of the above work.

From the begging this is the entry entered into the Wordpress post title...

```txt
Standard UK 4x4
```

When it saves, it saves the title into the database as a normal `x`...

```txt
Standard UK 4x4
```

When the post title is outputted in the Wordpress dashboard admin it uses `×` rather than `x`...

[image]

When I `var_dump` title using `get_the_title()` it outputs this...

[image]

```
string(20) "Standard UK 4×4"
```

And when I pass this title to stripes line-items it returns and replaces the `×` with `&#215;`...

[image]

I can't seem to figure out anyway to force the returned string to use a character `x` rather than automatically converting to a `×` symbol.

Any ideas would be really helpful.

Comment: Well `$newString = str_replace('&#215;','x', $title);` should work. Did you forget to put the result of `str_replace()` into a variable

Comment: Plus in your code above isn't defined `$title` var. You have somewhere a typo, not SO question.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks but tried storing it as a variable `$title = str_replace('&#215;','x',get_the_title($id));` and this is what it returns... `Standard UK 4×4`. My IDE also says you can remove unnecessary inline variable.

Comment: `var_dump($title)` before anything else gives what back? Please include string length as well, might have double encoded entity.

Comment: Not sure that this is gonna help you. But try `utf8_encode(get_the_title())`

Comment: No, they arent. `var_dump` gives back a string length

Comment: @user3783243 update question with var_dump results

Comment: @RavishaHesh thanks but `utf8_encode` still returned `string(20) "Standard UK 4×4"`

Comment: `Standard UK 4×4` is only 15 characters long so your `×` is an entity, not the character. View the page source and see what you really have there. `utf8_encode` is rarely a solution

Comment: @user3783243 I see that. But here is the source https://imgur.com/a/2Yt90lh. It's just so strange this character seems to crossing over into my stripe line items when it's all pure php using `get_the_title();`

Comment: Is that image the source or the developer console display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply convert unicode characters down to standard characters by using

```
$output = html_entity_decode($input, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

The first argument is your input string, `ENT_COMPAT` according to the documentation 'Will convert double-quotes and leave single-quotes alone.'

And your final argument `UTF-8` specifies the encoding you want to use when converting characters. UTF-8 is generally considered your standardised character set, particularly for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your editor or source file is not UTF-8 while the string is?

Try this:

```
$title = str_replace( "\xC3\x97", "x", $title );
```

Explanation: `C3 97` is the utf-8 encoding for the `×` symbol, and escaped like this it doesn't depend on the (assumed) encoding of the source file.

If not, can you try this:

```
echo bin2hex($title);
```

And see what hexadecimal output that produces?